# Read line from file issue

Tags: c

I wrote this simple `readline` function, <s>it can return each line length but it doesn't return a pointer to the allocated buffer</s>. Another issue is the last line ignored(it doesn't return it):

```
FILE *passFile = NULL;
char *current = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
passFile = fopen("pass.txt", "r");
while(readline(passFile, &current, &len) != -1) {
    printf("%s\n", current); // SEGMENTAION FAULT
    printf("%d\n", len);
    free(current);
    current = NULL;
}

ssize_t
readline(FILE *file, char **bufPtr, size_t *len)
{
    char c, *buf = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    while((c = fgetc(file)) != '\n' && (c != EOF)) {
        buf[n] = c;
        ++n;
        buf = realloc(buf, n + 1);
    }

    buf[n] = '\0';
    *bufPtr = buf;
    *len = n;
    if(c == EOF)    // reach end of file
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will not compile.

Comment: How's current defined?

Comment: Whoa, you just completely changed the program text in the question but you didn't change the question.  With the program as currently shown, are you having the problems?

Comment: @steveha right now, i can't read the last line from file due I am returning -1 if I encounter `EOF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works:

```
ssize_t
readline(FILE *file, char **bufPtr, size_t *len)
{
    if(feof(file))  // reach end of file
        return -1;

    char c, *buf = NULL;
    size_t n = 0, portion = CHUNK;
    buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * CHUNK);
    while((c = fgetc(file)) != '\n' && (c != EOF)) {
        buf[n] = c;
        ++n;
        if(n == portion) {
            buf = realloc(buf, CHUNK + n);
            portion += n;
        }
    }

    buf[n] = '\0';
    *bufPtr = buf;
    *len = n;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `readline()` function is not returning a pointer to allocated memory.  In your call, `current` is never set, so the pointer is invalid and you get the error.

In C, functions are "call by value".  Inside `readline()`, `bufPtr` is a copy of whatever was passed to `readline()`.  Assigning to `bufPtr` merely overwrites the local copy and does not return a value that the calling code can see.

In pseudocode:

```
TYPE a;

define function foo(TYPE x)
{
    x = new_value;
}

foo(a);  // does not change a
```

This only changes the local copy of `x` and does not return a value.  You change it to use a pointer... the function still gets a copy, but now it's a copy of a pointer, and it can use that pointer value to find the original variable.  In pseudocode:

```
TYPE a;

define function foo(TYPE *px)
{
    *px = new_value;
}

foo(&a);  // does change a
```

Now, to change your function:

```
ssize_t
readline(FILE *file, char **pbufPtr, size_t *len)
{
    // ...deleted...
    buf[n] = '\0';
    *pbufPtr = buf;
    // ...deleted...
}
```

And you call it like so:

```
while(readline(passFile, &current, &len) != -1)
```

P.S. It is not a good idea to call `realloc()` the way you do here.  It's potentially a very slow function, and for an input string of 65 characters you will call it 65 times.  It would be better to use an internal buffer for the initial file input, then use `malloc()` to allocate a string that is just the right size and copy the string into the buffer.  If the string is too long to fit in the internal buffer at once, use `malloc()` to get a big-enough place to copy out the part of the string you have in the internal buffer, then continue using the internal buffer to copy more of the string, and *then* call `realloc()` as needed.  Basically I'm suggesting you have an internal buffer of size N, and copy the string in chunks of N characters at a time, thus minimizing the number of calls to `realloc()` while still allowing arbitrary-length input strings.

EDIT: Your last-line problem is that you return -1 when you hit end of file, even though there is a line to return.

Change your code so that you return -1 only if `c == EOF` *and* `n == 0`, so a final line that ends with EOF will be correctly returned.

You should also make `readline()` use the `feof()` function to check if `file` is at end-of-file, and if so, return -1 without calling `malloc()`.

Basically, when you return -1, you don't want to call `malloc()`, and when you did call `malloc()` and copy data into it, you don't want to return -1!  -1 should mean "you got nothing because we hit end of file".  If you got something before we hit end of file, that's not -1, that is 0.  Then the *next* call to `readline()` after that will return -1.

Comment: I always have trouble with pointer to pointer. Now I have a problem with the last line, it never been read, some thing in my function logic wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In your `readline` function you pass `current` by value. So if you change `bufPtr` inside your function, it doesn't change value of `current` outside. If you want to change value of `current` pass it by reference: `&current` and change `readline()` parameter to `char **bufPTR`.
You could pass `current` the way you did if you wanted to change something it points to, but you want to change **where it points** in first place.

Answer (score 0):

replace your `readline`function with this

```
char*   readline(FILE *file, size_t *len)
{
    char c, *buf = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    while((c = fgetc(file)) != '\n' && (c != EOF)) {
        buf[n] = c;
        ++n;
        buf = realloc(buf, n + 1);
    }

    buf[n] = '\0';
    bufPtr = buf;
    *len = n;
    if(c == EOF)    // reach end of file
        return NULL;

    return buf;
}
```

and then in `main` replace this line `while(readline(passFile, current, &len) != -1)` with this `while((current = readline(passFile,  &len) != NULL)`